# Localize WooCommerce Extension

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, internationalization

I am developing WC extension by its new [way](https://developer.woocommerce.com/extension-developer-guide/designing-a-simple-extension/). Everything works like a charm instead of localization. I have generated JSON by `wp i18n make-json` and using in index.js like this:

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';

__( 'Verify licence', 'domain' );
```

Unfortunatelly the strings are never been translated. Should I load the JSON myself or register the script `wp_set_script_translations( 'domain-script', 'domain', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/languages' );`
?
At server side translations work. I am really confused about the JS translation flow. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For future generations the solution is simple.

You have to call something like this:

```
    public function extension_set_script_translations() {
        $loaded = wp_set_script_translations( 'extension', 'extension', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/languages' );
    }

    private function initLocalizations() {
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', [$this, 'extension_set_script_translations'] );
    }
```

Another important thing is name of the language JSON file.

```
{text-domain}-{locale}-{script-handle}.json
```